# How to upload large number of files to Amazon S3 efficiently using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have 10000s of 10Mb files in my local directory and I'm trying to upload it to a bucket in Amazon S3 using boto3 by sequential upload approach. The only problem I'm facing here is it takes lot of time to upload large number of files to S3. I want to know like whether there are efficient ways(using multithreading or multiprocessing) to upload files to Amazon S3?

```
root_path ="/home/shivraj/folder/"

path = root_path+'folder_raw/' # use your path
dest_path = root_path+'folder_parsed/'
backup_path = root_path+'folder_backup/'


def parse_ivn_files():
    src_files_list = glob.glob(path + "*.txt.zip") # .log files in the path files
    try:
        if src_files_list:
            for file_ in src_files_list:
                df = pd.read_csv(file_,compression="zip",sep="|", header=None)
                file = file_.replace(path,'')
                file_name = file.replace(".txt.zip",'')
                df.columns=["Date","Time","System_Event","Event_Type","Event_sub_type","Latitude","Longitude","Field_1","Field_2","Field_3","Field_4","Event_Number","Event_Description"]  
                new_df=df['Event_Description'].str.split(',',expand=True)         
                large_df = pd.concat([df,new_df],axis=1)   
                large_df.to_csv(dest_path+file_name+".csv",index=False)
                s3.meta.client.upload_file(dest_path+file_name+".csv", 's3-bucket-name-here', 'ivn_parsed/'+file_name+".csv")
                s3.meta.client.upload_file(path+file_name+".txt.zip", 's3-bucket-name-here', 'ivn_raw_backup/'+file_name+"_bk.txt.zip")
                os.rename(path+file_name+".txt.zip", backup_path+file_name+"_bk.txt.zip")
        else:
            print("No files in the source folder")


    except:
            raise FileNotFoundError
```

Comment: [Amazon Snowball](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/ug/whatissnowball.html) is a left field option that you should perhaps consider.

Comment: You probably need to run your code with multiple threads in parallel. My guess is that at some point you will either bottleneck on CPU utilization (in gzip decompress), disk I/O (reading bytes off of local storage) or network I/O (pushing bytes to S3). Which one you get stuck at determines what you need to move forward. But to get stuck at any of them you'll need to start operating on multiple files in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. I will look into them.

Comment: Before going down the path of multi-threading, you need to analyze your current throughput and available bandwidth. If you have a gigabit connection to the Internet, then yes, you could probably improve your performance by separating the processes of read, compress, and write. But if you're sharing a 25 megabit connection (or slower) with a bunch of other people, you're probably running into bandwidth limitations.

Comment: @kdgregory the implications of bandwidth-delay product for TCP suggest that there is almost always *some* benefit from parallelizing.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - sure, "some" benefit. The question is whether the benefit will exceed the cost of implementation, which can only be reasonably determined if you know what the available bandwidth is and how fast the current process runs. Two things that the OP still has not seen fit to share.

Comment: @kdgregory, touché.  Fair points.

Answer (score 1):

I’d go for s4cmd - it’s a nice tool that can upload your files in parallel and has solved some other problems too:

https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd